# Spotlight search indexing not working in ios11?

Tags: ios11, corespotlight, xcode9-beta

I indexed the content of my app so that I can search for it in spotlight and also can continue the search inside the app. With iOS 10 it is working, with iOS 11 it doesn't seem to work neither on my device nor in the simulator. Do I have to add anything for iOS11 or is it not working in beta versions?

(strange, the search field seems to be missing in the ios11 iPhone 6s simulator, but is available in the simulator for iPhone7 with ios11.)

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue? Seeing the same behaviour in iOS 11 GM.

Comment: No, but I didn't try anymore since.

Comment: Me too... Have you solved it?

Comment: No, but I still did not try since.